# Download speed for pip install inside docker container very slow

Tags: docker, pip

While creating a docker image from a dockerfile or being inside the created container, `pip install <package>` in a conda environment is super slow.

The download speed hugely differs if I do the same without docker. 
I tried to change the mirror `pip install -i http:pypi.doubanio.com/simple <package>` and can gain slight improvements, but still different inside and outside of docker.
Testing the download speed inside the container via `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -` gives me the expected good results.

Answer (score 17):

I suggest building with the `--network host` when running docker build. This will guarantee the RUN instructions to use the host network directly. That way you will be sure that slowness is not related to docker.